# How to create a landing div with image that fits the page and have the possibility to scroll to other content

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, css-position

I am trying to make an image inside my div set up as background of that div, so that it always fits the screen, something like this http://richhaagenson.com/. I am having trouble with setting it up, it is either set up as position:absolute and then it is ok, but I can't add any content under that div. I want it to cover the entire page like on this website and that it is possible to add content under it, when scrolling. Here is my code so far

```
<section>
<div id="landing" class="landing-part">
<img src="images/background.jpg">
</div>
 </section>

<section>
<div id="about">About me bla bla bla bla bla</div>
</section>
```

My CSS

```
.landing-part img{  
width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:-5000;
}
#about{
width:400px;
height: 500px;
background-color: red;  
}
```

Comment: Just make the `section` 100% height (or 100vh`) of the viewport

Comment: I did, and it also makes the image fit the screen and leaves blank space between image and that second div. I want it to have width and height of the browsers window, not image resolution.

Comment: The use it as a background image not inline.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a landing page, you can use the `background-url` and the `background-size` properties in css to select your image directory and specify the size respectively.

```
.landing-part {
    background: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-size: 800px 600px;
}
```

You can vary the dimensions and check the result until it fits your screen.